# If $A$ is open then $\overline{Int(Bd(A))}=\emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$.

I wanted to prove that $\overline{Int(Bd(A))} = \overline{A\cap Int(Bd(A))}$. I already proved that (or I think so), but I don't urdestand it well. Let's see:

We suppose that $A$ is open, then it is clear that $\overline{A\cap Int(Bd(A))}=\overline{A\cap Int(\overline A\setminus A)}=\emptyset$

But, how would we show that if $A$ is open, then $\overline{Int(Bd(A))}=\emptyset$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would we show that if $A$ is open, then $Int(Bd(A))=\emptyset$?

Since $A$ is open, $Bd(A)\subseteq X\setminus A$. Therefore, any interior point of $Bd(A)$ is also an interior point of $X\setminus A$. But then it can't be a boundary point of $A$, which is a contradiction.